# How to retrieve list of images from GridFS?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

This is to submit a view that uses ajax to pull the data.

I am trying to retrieve an image from MongoDb GridFS bucket. The download operation works. But the issue is, the view model that I use has:

```
public User User { get; set; }
public List<IFormFile> ImageUpload { get; set; }
```

I get the user from the db context, and use that to identify the image from the bucket and I want to return it to the view from the controller.

The following is my controller code:

```
public IActionResult AddEditUser(int id = 0)
        {
            if (id == 0)
            {
                return View(new UserImgBinder());
            }
            else
            {
                var userImageId = _context.User.Where(x => x.UserId.Equals(id)).Select(y => y.AvatarImg).ToString();
                var stream = ContextNew.ImagesBucket.OpenDownloadStream(new ObjectId(userImageId.ToBson()));
                var contentType = stream.FileInfo.Metadata["ContentType"].AsString;
                //File(stream, contentType);
                IFormFile file = new  FormFile(stream, 0, stream.Length,"",""); 


                var UserImgBinder = new UserImgBinder
                {
                    User = _context.User.Where(x => x.UserId.Equals(id)).FirstOrDefault(),
                    ImageUpload = file
            };
                return View(UserImgBinder);
            }

        }
```

Since ImageUpload is of type List and what I am trying to feed it is not a list I am getting error.

What should I write to solve this? Is this approach bad?
Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Each user has multiple images?
In that case you can create a new list and add the retrieved image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try code like:

```
var UserImgBinder = new UserImgBinder
{
    User = _context.User.Where(x => x.UserId.Equals(id)).FirstOrDefault(),
    ImageUpload = new List<IFormFile> {
                file
            }
};
```

Comment: thanks mate. That issue is resolved. Mind if I ask you a question? 
The above code, when id=0, will show new user add view, if not it will pick up id and show edit view.
What i expected was the above code to magically post the IFormfile back to the view where I am trying to edit the user data and the file name would show besides the upload button. Can you please let me know what I am missing? Tx

Comment: @Neo It is impossible to send the `IFormfile` from server side to client side.